# Postgres superuser privilege disappeared

Tags: postgres-14

I've installed Postgres 14 on Ubuntu 22.04. I use pgAdmin as postgres-User to work on it.
Everything worked fine until after a few days i realized that the superuser privilege was deactivated for the postgres-User.

I managed to reactivate it but happened again after a few days.
So I created another user with superuser privilege but this one also got the superuser privilege deactivated after a few days.
I even reinstalled Ubuntu and Postgres, but it still happens. I am the only one that works on this installation, so there is nobody else who could change this setting for any reason.

Any idea what could be the reason for that behavior?